# Trying to create a quiz with java, but something went wrong. What part of my program did i screw up?

Tags: java

So I'm starting to get the hang of java, and I'm creating a quiz as a mini project. However, when I get to the input part of my program, it breaks down. What's going on?
I also apologize for the formatting

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    int total = 0;


    System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz? (Y/N)");
    char answer = in.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
    {
        String a = "Barrow";
        String b = "Juneau";
        String c = "Anchorage";
        String d = "Annapolis";


        System.out.println("Alright! Lets get right to it!");
        System.out.println("What is the Capital of Alaska?");
        System.out.println("A: " + a);
        System.out.println("B: " + b);
        System.out.println("C: " + c);
        System.out.println("D: " + d);
        char choice = in.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
            if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b')
            {
                System.out.println("Good Job! 1 point for you!");
                score = score + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect! the answer was actually " + b);
            }

        String e = "Yes";
        String f = "No";
        System.out.println("Alright, Next Question! Can you"
        + " store the value 'cat' in a variable of type int?");
        System.out.println("A: " + e);
        System.out.println("B: " + f);
        char secchoice = in.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
            if (secchoice == 'A' || secchoice == 'a')
            {
                System.out.println("Correct! Good Job!");
                score = score + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }

        System.out.println("What is the result of 2+2X3-5?");
        int result = in.nextInt();
            if (result == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct! Good Job!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }

        System.out.println("Your total score was " + score + "out of 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *it breaks down* is not a meaningful problem description, and *where did I screw up?* is not a specific question. Please [edit] your question to be more specific about the problem you're having and ask a question that can be answered. If you need help doing so, see [ask], take the [tour], and read through the [help] pages.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException on line 26 [because of the way that findInLine() works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.util.regex.Pattern)). Basically, you have used up the one line of input you give it when it starts and the Scanner has advanced passed it to find the next one (which does not exist). In other words, you should use another method for Scanner or use an entirely different approach for getting input.

For example, it is preferable to use this technique

```
char answer = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

because nextLine() [will wait until it has more input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

Of course, you will have to come up with some way to parse the input from the user to make sure that it is valid (i.e. if they can only choose between 'Y' and 'N' you handle the case where they choose neither).

That would look something like

```
char answer = parseInput(in.nextLine().charAt(0));
```

where parseInput(String s) is a method you write yourself.

As far as other approaches go, [this tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) can help you get started.